# C# Inheritance - Updating Base Classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I'm working on updating one of my systems to a more DDD orientated approach and looking at eliminating anemic domain models from my program.

I'm trying to understand best practices for updating a base class from a child.

I have two classes. (Simplified below)

```
public class WorkItem
{
   public int Y {get; private set;}
   public int X {get; private set;}

   public void Update(int x, int y)
   {
      Validate(x);
      Validate(y);

      X = x;
      Y = y;
   }

   public void Validate(int x)
    {
      ///Validation rules here
    }

}


public class Ticket:WorkItem
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Z {get; set;}
}
```

This is a web application so I could be updating a ticket. So lets assume I have a service that looks something like this right now

```
public void UpdateTicket(int Id)
 {
    var ticket = _context.Tickets.Where(c=>c.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();  
    //Update Tickets

   _context.SaveChanges();       
 }
```

I want to be able to Update the fields in the Workitem class as well as the ticket class all at once whilst running the Validate Method.

Heres the options I've come up with:

Option A

```
public class Ticket:WorkItem
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public int Z {get; set;}

 public void Update(int x, int y, int z)
 {
  base.Validate(z);
  base.Update(x, y);
  Z=z;
 }
 }
```

Adding an update method in the child that calls the update method in the parent. This starts to feel messy if I add another level of inheritance as I have to pass the parent members from the bottom to the top.

Option B:

```
 public class Ticket:WorkItem
 {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Z {get; set;}

  public void Update(int x, int y, int z)
  {
   base.Validate(z)
   base.Validate(x)
   base.Validate(y)

   X = x;
   Y = y;
   Z = z;
  }
 }
```

Updating the properties inside the child's update method explicitly without calling the Update method in the parent. This approach feels better but for some reason still doesnt feel right

I'm not entirely sure either of these approaches are correct, please can you recommend the best approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: One option to consider - Create a `ValidateThenUpdate` method in the base class (`WorkItem`). Add a virtual `Validate` method in the base class (with no parameters, which validates all of the properties of the class at that level). Add a virtual `Update` method in the base class. `ValidateThenUpdate` calls `Validate` then `Update`. Your `Ticket` class will inherit the base class and override `Validate` and `Update` (including calls to `base.Validate` etc).

Comment: Maybe you should think about composition instead of inheritance? A ticket should have a workitem as a member. Each object should have it's own methods and implement it's own interface. It looks like you are using a DB behind the scenes as well, so it will be easier to use two different tables with a foreign key connecting them. Plus, I believe that there are tickets that don't have workitems connected to them..

Comment: @mjwills If the method is parameterless then how would the class know which fields need to be updated and validated?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the x, y, and z to `Update`? why not just make the setters public on X and Y and in Update validate on the properties? this way you can make it virtual and override (alternatively, just call validate in the setters themselves, if that makes more sense to your usage)

Comment: I would envisage a model whereby the properties were read-write (as opposed to your current read-only). The caller sets the properties, then calls `ValidateThenUpdate`. _Basically what @KMoussa said._

Comment: @AmirPopovich We considered using composition but a Ticket is definitely a WorkItem as opposed to 'has a' WorkItem. Tickets cannot exist without a corresponding WorkItem, we still have two different tables in the database but the Ticket table uses the WorkItemID as its primary key.

Comment: @MarkTallentire - In that case, why do you need two different objects? Why not use a WorkItem only that will contain all the Ticket's properties?
If you insist on inheritance, then instead of using a Update method, use setters on each property that will call inner class methods instead. That's a lot cleaner approach if you ask me..

Comment: @KMoussa Possibly a miss-understanding on my part of how classes should be responsible for their own state?. My understanding of this is that a class should always be responsible for making sure it's state is valid -  meaning that it would need to be responsible for validating and updating itself?  Updating via public setters mean that I'm making the service responsible for updating the fields of my class?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no correct/incorrect approach by itself. The correctness depends on the problems you're trying to solve. If your concern is extensibility without possible modifications of existing entities consider logic decoupling. That is decouple your validation logic from the entities logic. The good example of such decoupling is [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

Comment: @AmirPopovich We have multiple different types that are also workitems so we can't just place Ticket properties on the workitem itself.

Comment: Option A  is the one closest to your design. It keeps it DRY. That it feels 'messy' is due to the overall design.

Comment: @MarkTallentire - I understand. I'd go with setters on properties that will internally call virtual methods in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is pretty long then be patient a go though each refactoring step with me.

Option A is definitely better because you do not duplicate behavior in derived classes however I wonder what the function of `Update()` is. The exactly same run-time behavior might be obtained with:

```
abstract class WorkItem {
    public int X {
        get => _x;
        set {
            Validate(value);
            _x = value;
        }
    }

    private int _x;
}
```

What do you need a separate method for? Fictional names make harder to reason about your logic but it might have sense if `Update()` is actually a high level action, in that case a combination of the above might work:

```
abstract class WorkItem {
    public int Quantity {
        get => _quantity;
        protected set {
            Validate(value);
            _quantity = value;
        }
    }

    // Other properties

    // Single method because you cannot change quantity without
    // affecting discount (and vice-versa).
    UpdateOrder(int newQuantity, float discount) {
        Quantity = newQuantity;
        Discount = discount; // Discount validation is maybe affected by Quantity
    }

    private int _quantity;
}
```

With an hypothetical derived class:

```
sealed class InternationalOrder : Workitem {
    public UpdateOrder(int quantity, float discount, string address) {
        Address = address;

        // Address may affect discount eligibility
        UpdateOrder(quantity, discount);
    }
}
```

Of course this is fictional but you should rely on existing behavior when possible. Even better there should not be a *generic* `UpdateXyz()` method (and often not even public setters) but *actions* like `ChangeDeliveryDate()`, `Cancel()` or `Postpone()`. The advantage is to abstract the state from the business rules.

What if validation is expensive or there are many internal dependencies? In the previous example the order you set properties matters and it's a *bad thing*. You may validate once all together:

```
abstract class WorkItem {
    public virtual void Validate() {
        if (Discount > MaximumDiscount)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Discount is way to high!");

        if (Quantity < MinimumQuantityForDiscount)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Order is not eligible for discount.");
    }
}

sealed class OnlineOrder : WorkItem {
    public override Validate() {
        base.Validate();

        // More validation rules, specific for OnlineOrder
    }
}
```

Basic property validation is NOT part of the DDD logic and IMHO must be in-place:

```
public int Quantity {
    get => _quantity;
    set {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");

        _quantity = value;
    }
}
```

When `Validate()` has to be called?

- Each time you change a property (internally implementing a mechanism similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`). This is the easiest way but it might impact performance if validation is extremely complex or slow (for example with thousands business rules, possibly with data from external data sources. Note that business rules validation should not be a class responsibility for any non-trivial scenario.
- Manually inside your `UpdateTicket()` method before you call `SaveChanges()`. Obvious drawback is that caller might *forget* to call it.
- A combination of the above.

I obviously prefer the third option: make it automatic and have in-place a mechanism to temporarily disable validation when performing a *bulk* update. Proof of concept:

```
abstract class WorkItem {
    public int Quantity {
        get => _quantity;
        protected set {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");

            if (_quantity != value) {
                _quantity = value;
                Validate();
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void Validate() {
        if (_isValidationDisabled)
            return;

        if (Discount > MaximumDiscount)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Discount is way to high!");

        if (Quantity < MinimumQuantityForDiscount)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Order is not eligible for discount.");
    }

    public void BeginUpdate() {
        _isValidationDisabled = true;
    }

    public void EndUpdate() {
        _isValidationDisabled = false;
        Validate();
    }

    private bool _isValidationDisabled;
    private int _quantity;
}
```

Of course you want to extract a reusable `SetBackingStore()` method to set the value of a field and call `Validate()`.

It will be used like this:

```
public void UpdateTicket(int Id) {
    var ticket = _context.Tickets.Where(c => c.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();  
    if (ticket == null) { /* no ticket? */ }

    ticket.BeginUpdate();
    tickets.Status = TicketStatus.Resolved;
    ticked.ResolvedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    ticket.EndUpdate();

    _context.SaveChanges();       
}
```

Final thought: that `BeginUpdate()`/`EndUpdate()` tuple really bother me (what in case of errors? What if caller forgets to call `EndUpdate()`?) Create a simple `IDisposable` class that does the job for you (let it be a nested class to have access to private state) to be able to write:

```
public void UpdateTicket(int Id) {
    var ticket = _context.Tickets.Where(c => c.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();  
    if (ticket == null) { /* no ticket? */ }

    using (ticket.BeginUpdate()) {
        tickets.Status = TicketStatus.Resolved;
        ticked.ResolvedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();       
}
```

We still have a bad smell here, those setters (or equivalent methods Java-style like `UpdateStatus(TicketStatus.Resolved, DateTime.Now)`) are a missed chance to introduce an abstraction:

```
public void UpdateTicket(int Id) {
    var ticket = _context.Tickets.Where(c => c.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();  
    if (ticket == null) { /* no ticket? */ }

    ticket.Close();

    _context.SaveChanges();       
}
```

Close method might be implemented exactly as in the previous example (don't forget to reuse existing *behaviors* whenever possible):

```
void Close() {
    tickets.Status = TicketStatus.Resolved;
    ticked.ResolvedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Validate();
}
```

It's not always possible to have such high-level methods (for example when editing an object properties...) then keep that `BeginUpdate()` in-place for those cases.

Comment: You're right that my validate method doesn't just do basic validation and does something more like if(Completed && ReviewDate != null) //remove reviewdate. It's more of an integritycheck than a validation check. I like your answer, however option 3 is not DDD right? In DDD you would have a method such as UpdateTicketStatus(Status) instead of setting it in the service?

Comment: `UpdateTicketStatus()` or `ticket.Status = ...` are pretty much the exact same thing. DDD is generic and not all languages have properties (let's try to rewrite same example in Java)`. The biggest design smell here is probably that we should have _high-level_ actions instead of dumb setters (but it's harder to figure out a good example with fictional objects...). I mean: instead of calling `UpdateTicketStatus(TicketStatus.Closed)` you should have a single method `Close()`. I added an example of that.

Comment: Thank you for that last edit. That feels much more how I had it in my head. If we were to introduce the inheritance angle back to this and say that Ticket has a Status enum property and WorkItem contains a simple bool for completed. Would Ticket.Close() do something like Ticket.Status = Resolved; WorkItem.Completed = true; Validate(); base.Validate(); with the seperate validates ensuring that both the rules for Tickets get validated as well as the rules for the WorkItem(); (I appreciate you could also call base.Validate inside Ticket.Validate.

Comment: Yep, if `IsCompleted` cannot be deduced from the state of existing properties. Also in this case I'd imagine a `Resolve()` method (in base class) and a `Close()` method in derived class (where `Close()` will call `Resolve()` as appropriate). I'd call `base.Validate()` only inside `Validate()`, why to have to remember to do it each time you need it? What if you remove the base class in favor of an interface?

Comment: We're using WorkItem for dashboards (such as total count of open items) so it makes it easier having that bool there (We have multiple derived classes). Forgetting to call a base validate would cause issues as it would mean that the Ticket and WorkItem status is no longer in sync. In any case, I've accepted your answer, thank you for the thorough response and answering my follow ups.

Comment: Hmmmmmm In general but maybe especially if you're following DDD then `IsCompleted` does not belong to the domain model. It's an UI thing and as such it should be in the View Model (or, at least, in the UI logic if you do not have a separate VM).

Comment: I think I'm being pragmatic here though, using the bool means I don't have to query the tables of each derived type to check whatever combination of fields tells me its completed. I can just do a simple workitems.Where(c=>c.completed == true).count() and be done.

Comment: Well, it might be done with a calculated column in the DB but I'm almost sure that EF won't make this easy. Shhhhh just don't tell to any SQL guy...